# Is it a grammar error to connect two verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I found the following example sentence in my dictionary.

> She renewed her promise to come see me.

Is it an error to connect *come* and *see*? My friend says it's *come and see* but the *and* got omitted. Is it true? Thanks.

Comment: Circumstances alter cases, but conjunction ***and*** is often "optional" between ***come/go*** used as an "auxiliary", and the "main" verb that follows. Sometimes it's actually *required*, but sometimes it's completely non-idiomatic to include it. But I think most native speakers would agree that omitting the conjunction in your *specific* example is at the very least a "casual, relaxed informal" usage.  ***Go figure***.

Comment: (Note that in a more formal register, you might encounter *She renewed her promise to come **to see** me*.)